# Не создаёт Navigator Drawer Activity

Tags: android, xml, activity

Хочу создать активити,Нажимаю new>activity >Navigator drawer.
Дальше создаётся только Navigator.xml и всё. Что Делать?

Comment: это довольно странное поведение, потому что я вот попробовал у себя добавить такую активность и все нормально подтянулось, у вас студия последней версии? добавьте пожалуйста больше конкретики в вопрос, потому что так довольно сложно помочь

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Очистить кэш и перезагрузить Android Studio